# Koin dependency Injection Isssue - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

In my android application am using MVVM architecture and using koin library for DI.
Below is my Repository class:

```
class JaiminRepository constructor(
    private var remoteDataSource : RemoteDataSource,
    private var enrollApiInterface : EnrollApiInterface
) {
   ...
  }
```

Created module for is as below:

```
val jaiminRepositoryModule = module {

    single {
        JaiminRepository(get(),get())
    }

}
```

For this I am getting error as :

> Instance creation error : could not create instance for
> [Singleton:'com.jaimin.sdk.repository.JaiminRepository']:
> org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found
> for class:'com.jaimin.api.RemoteDataSource'. Check your definitions!
> org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:287)
> org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:257)

So I have added factory for RemoteDataSource.

```
factory {
    RemoteDataSource()
}
```

and finally it look like as below:

```
val jaiminRepositoryModule = module {

        factory {
            RemoteDataSource()
        }

        single {
            JaiminRepository(get(),get())
        }

    }
```

But still am getting error. What might be the issue? Do I need to do something with **EnrollApiInterface** also? Please guide. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define all dependencies in the module(or another module), otherwise your repository can't be created. Make sure you also provide the `EnrollApiInterface`:

```
val jaiminRepositoryModule = module {

    factory<EnrollApiInterface> {
        EnrollApiInterfaceImpl()
    }

    factory {
        RemoteDataSource()
    }

    single {
        JaiminRepository(get(),get())
    }

}
```

Comment: EnrollApiInterface is an interface. While writing factory for it, displays "Required EnrollApiInterface, found Unit"

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's an interface or a class, you have to provide it so koin can find it. How you provide it is up to you, the code I provided is just an example. You can also use `object: EnrollApiInterface {…` instead of EnrollApiInterfaceImpl in the factory.